# Programmatically create tabBarController in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've been following lot's of different tutorials on how to add a UITabBarController programmatically. This would be easy to achieve using storyboard, but since I'm trying to learn how to do things programmatically I can't do that.

At the moment I've got this code in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *tabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[MenuViewController alloc] init]];

[tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];

[tabs addObject:navController];


[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

**Edited code:**

```
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

MenuViewController *firstTab = [[MenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navController];
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

This does not do anything to my `rootViewController` called `MenuViewController`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thie bellow code for 5 tab UITabbarcontroller try with this bellow code:-

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

anasayfaViewController * firstTab= [[anasayfaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"anasayfaViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstTab];

SehirRehberiViewController *sehirRehberi = [[SehirRehberiViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SehirRehberiViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sehirRehberi];

duyuruViewController *duyuru = [[duyuruViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"duyuruViewController" bundle:nil]; 
UINavigationController *navigationController3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:duyuru];

sikayetViewController *sikayet = [[sikayetViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"sikayetViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sikayet];

digerViewController *diger = [[digerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"digerViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:diger];


self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[navigationController1,navigationController2,navigationController3,navigationController4,navigationController5];

 [self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: i've tried using your code and just starting with 1 tab, but i get the error Could not load NIB in bundle  with name 'MenuViewController'. I've added the code to the question. Do i need to add MenuViewController somewhere?

Comment: that menu view controll its my project viewcontroller you need to put your own viewcontroller that in to your project this is command think and logic else you are not connect correctly your view contrller object

Comment: i'm sorry i do not see you having a projectViewController in your code above.

Comment: menuviewcontrller this is in to your project than not linked properly sir

Answer (score 1):

You should add tab bar controller as a root view controller:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

also it's a good idea to first add object to array and after that do something with it, (other way round):

```
[tabs addObject:navController];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:tabs];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UIViewController *viewController_favorites = [[[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController_project = [[[ProjectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProjectViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController_search = [[[Search alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search" bundle:nil] autorelease];
UIViewController *viewController_setting = [[[SettingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

UINavigationController *navController_favorite = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController_favorites] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController_project = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController_project] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController_search = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController_search] autorelease];


self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController_favorite,navController_project,navController_search,viewController_setting, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a `UITabBarController` as your app's rootViewcontroller you can add this code to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

It adds a navigation controller containing a list controller and a simple view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
  UITabBarController*     tabBarController           = [[UITabBarController     alloc] init];
  UITableViewController*  myListController           = [[MyListController       alloc] init];
  UINavigationController* navigationControllerMyList = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myListController];
  navigationControllerMyList.tabBarItem              = [[UITabBarItem           alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemFavorites tag:0];

  UIViewController* simpleViewController             = [[SimpleViewController   alloc] init];
  simpleViewController.tabBarItem                    = [[UITabBarItem           alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:0];
  tabBarController.viewControllers                   = @[ navigationControllerMyList , simpleViewController ];

  self.window                    = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
  self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```